# Boolean type in Postgres does not work as expected

Tags: postgresql, boolean

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.14.

I just encountered a really weird case. The sum of three states of `boolean` is not equal to the whole count.

[image]

This is `deleted` field attribute default as false.

I tried:

The whole count:

```
SELECT count(*) from table; the count -> 9000
```

The un-deleted count:

```
SELECT count(*) from table where deleted; the count -> 400;
```

Same as:

```
SELECT count(*) from table where deleted = true; the count -> 400;
```

The deleted count:

```
SELECT count(*) from table where not deleted; the count -> 0;
```

Same as:

```
SELECT count(*) from table where deleted <> true; the count -> 0;
```

And the `null` case is:

```
SELECT count(*) from table where deleted = null; the count -> 0;
```

I checked the [official doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-boolean.html).

> PostgreSQL provides the standard SQL type boolean. The boolean type can have several states: "true", "false", and a third state, "unknown", which is represented by the SQL null value.

But as you can see, that final sum from the three states cannot be `9000`.

So surprisingly annoyed.

Please share some advice for this, thank you!

Comment: `SELECT count(*) from info_security_group where deleted IS null;`, not equal

Comment: That's one of the reasons I always define `boolean` columns as `NOT NULL` with `false` as the default value

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `IS NULL` to compare a column against `NULL`:

```
select count(*) from info_security_group where deleted is null;
```

My guess is that this will return a count of 8600.